# Using jackson to extract inner JSON array list

Tags: java, json, rest, jackson

My API needs to return a list of entry objects from the JSON below. I am using jersey and jackson. I would ideally like to only create a java class PermissionEnty , and my API to return a list of PermissionEntry objects from the JSON. I am not able to deserialize using the below approach? Can someone advise what could be the issue? I have added UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE so I presume the 'list' node it ignored, and I would get items below 'list' node.

```
public class PermissionEntry {

    private String id;
    private String displayName;
    private String memberType;
}
```

and the json;

```
{
    "list": {
        "pagination": {
            "count": 5,
            "hasMoreItems": false,            
        },
        "entries": [
            {
                "entry": {
                    "displayName": "norma",
                    "id": "norma",
                    "memberType": "PERSON"
                }
            },              
            {
                "entry": {
                    "displayName": "clara",
                    "id": "clara",
                    "memberType": "PERSON"
                }
            },
            {
                "entry": {
                    "displayName": "michael",
                    "id": "mich",
                    "memberType": "PERSON"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

PermissionEntries

```
public class PermissionEntries {
  @JsonProperty(value = "entries")
    @JsonDeserialize(using = PermissionEntryDeserializer.class)
    private List<PermissionEntry> entries;

    public List<PermissionEntry> getEntries() {
        return entries;
    }

    public void setEntries(List<PermissionEntry> entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
    }
}
```

Below is the deserializer that I am using

```
public class PermissionEntryDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<PermissionEntry>> {

    private static final String ENTRY = "entries";
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper()
            .configure(DeserializationFeature.UNWRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    private static final CollectionType collectionType =
            TypeFactory
                    .defaultInstance()
                    .constructCollectionType(List.class, PermissionEntry.class);

    @Override
    public List<PermissionEntry> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
            throws IOException {

        ObjectNode objectNode = mapper.readTree(jsonParser);
        JsonNode nodeEntries = objectNode.get(ENTRY);

        if (null == nodeEntries                     // if no ENTRY node could be found
                || !nodeEntries.isArray()           // or ENTRY node is not an array
                || !nodeEntries.elements().hasNext())   // or ENTRY node doesn't contain any entry
            return null;

        return mapper.readerFor(collectionType).readValue(nodeEntries);
    }
}
```

Service API

```
public Optional<List<PermissionEntry>> getPermissionsForGroup(String groupName) {
            Response response = getTarget()
                    .path("/api/group/" + groupName + "/members")
                    .request()
                    .get();

                PermissionEntries list = response.readEntity(PermissionEntries.class);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you mean in this question '*Can someone please tell me how many java classes do I need to create to get a list of entries.*' but you had already an entry object called `PermissionEntry`. You will have the **list** of this object.

This is the `jersey` client of your data with `jakcson` .

```
 ClientConfig clientConfig = new DefaultClientConfig();
 clientConfig.getFeatures().put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, Boolean.TRUE);
 Client client = Client.create(clientConfig);

 String URL = "http://{{host}}:{{port}}/entry";
 WebResource webResourceGet = client.resource(URL);
 ClientResponse response = webResourceGet.accept("application/json").get(ClientResponse.class);
 String output = response.getEntity(String.class);
 ResponseList responseList= mapper.readValue(output , ResponseList .class);//here is the permissionEntry list that you wil have
```

Also, you should create an object given name as `Pagination` for *pagination* that is in the `json` data. You can make an another object that includes `List<PermissionEntry>` and `Pagination` called `ResponseList`.

Comment: I have added additional class and deserializer that I am using. I don't know if this is correct approach. I am not able to deserialize as I expect to. I dont want to create an object for list and or the root node.

Comment: edited your comment by mistake, please discard my edit on your comment.